# How to know whether the List View is Active or not?

Tags: android

Hai dude,
         I developed an application which intially displayed Games Listview , suppose if the user clicks the football elemnet in that games listview, then the football listview opens ,in that if user selected the particular player listview, then it is displayed, my problem is i want 2 know which listview is in active.

Can any one help me regarding on this?

```
if(tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 2)
                    {  
                        Log.v("I m Here Boss","0");
                        if(findViewById(R.id.bars_school_details).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            Log.v("I m Here Boss","1");
                            findViewById(R.id.bars_school_details).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            findViewById(R.id.bars_list).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            findViewById(R.id.bars).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else if(findViewById(R.id.bars_list).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        {
                            Log.v("I m Here Boss","2");
                            findViewById(R.id.bars_school_details).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            findViewById(R.id.bars_list).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            findViewById(R.id.bars).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: @Mayra: actually i have two activity namely games & studies activity , i m using tabhost frnd, with the help of tabHost.getCurrentTab(), i know games activity is in process, but my aim is to know what is the listview currently viewed by the user to show the maximum Listview viewed by User.

Comment: I'm still not following... The games activity has a tab view with 2 tabs, each with a ListView?  Doesn't getCurrentTab tell you which is visible then?

Comment: @Mayra: I m posting my sample code

Comment: So the log statements don't tell you which is visible?

Comment: @Mayra: I m getting null pointer exception  if(findViewById(R.id.bars_school_details).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution for this, i changed my code as

```
try {
                    if(tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 2)
                    { 
                      try{

                            if(BS_.lv_bardate.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            {
                                BS_Bars.lv_bardate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                BS_Bars.lv_barlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                BS_Main.tv.setText("Schools");
                                BS_Bars.lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                            if(BS_Bars.lv_barlist.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            {
                                BS_Bars.lv_bardate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                BS_Main.tv.setText("Dates");
                                BS_Bars.lv_barlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                BS_Bars.lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }


    if(BS_Bars.sv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                                {
                                    BS_Bars.lv_bardate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    BS_Bars.lv_barlist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    BS_Bars.lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }



    if(BS_Bars.lv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                                {
    //                              BS_Bars.lv_bardate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //                              BS_Bars.lv_barlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //                              BS_Bars.lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    finish();
                                }

                            }

                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.v("BSMain","Error in Bar Module Back Button");
                        }
                    }
```